# Getting Object(...) is not a function on my drag and drop context. I'm using React

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

Using react-big-scheduler for my app and it require drag and drop context. So when I import and set it up I get Object(...) is not a function

I have also tried using  as a react component in the render and that gave Element type is invalid.

withDnDContext.js

```
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend);
```

propertyCalander.jsx (this is where I am using the scheduler)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Scheduler, {
  SchedulerData,
  ViewTypes,
  DemoData
} from 'react-big-scheduler';
// import { DragDropContextProvider } from 'react-dnd';
// import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

import withDragDropContext from './withDnDContext';
import 'react-big-scheduler/lib/css/style.css';


class PropertyCalnder extends Component { // eslint-disable-line
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const schedulerData = new SchedulerData('2017-12-18', ViewTypes.Week);
    schedulerData.localeMoment.locale('en');
    schedulerData.setResources(DemoData.resources);
    schedulerData.setEvents(DemoData.events);
    this.state = {
      viewModel: schedulerData
    };
  }

  prevClick = e => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  nextClick = e => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  onSelectDate = e => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  onViewChange = e => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  eventClicked = e => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  render() {
    const { viewModel } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {/* <DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}> */}
        <Scheduler
          schedulerData={viewModel}
          prevClick={this.prevClick}
          nextClick={this.nextClick}
          onSelectDate={this.onSelectDate}
          onViewChange={this.onViewChange}
          eventItemClick={this.eventClicked}
        />
        {/* </DragDropContextProvider> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withDragDropContext(PropertyCalnder);
```

package.json

```
...

"react-dnd": "^7.5.0",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dnd-html5-backend": "^7.5.0",
"react-big-scheduler": "^0.2.5",



It should just show the demo page as linked here https://stephenchou1017.github.io/scheduler/#/

but instead getting Object(...) is not a function
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, But with following packages it works fine. This issue comes when you update react-big-scheduler to "0.2.7"

```
"react-dnd": "5.0.0",
"react-dnd-html5-backend": "5.0.1",
"react-big-scheduler": "0.2.6",
```

you can run this command

```
"npm i react-big-scheduler@0.2.6"
```